# Share link in private message on fb-messenger:// url scheme from web JS function

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, url-scheme, facebook-messenger

I was wondering if there was a way, from a web js function, to share a link a on private message on facebook messenger app using url scheme such as fb-messenger://new (which open facebook messenger on new message if the user has the app on its device).

I can't find anything about url parameters allowing to embed a link.
Does someone has an idea about how we could do that?

thanks

Comment: Why not use the Facebook SDK?

Comment: This is what Im doing, the Javascript SDK on a web page, but I would work with the app itself instead of a modal, if that's possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the Send Button is the only official way: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Messenger App (e.g. Chat Bot) and have Webhooks set up, you can now use the Messenger Plugins too:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference